# Creating an overflow which minimised when there isn't enough room in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I have been trying to figure out the least impactful way of creating an overflow when there isn't enough room to show otherwise, 3 button icons. Ideally, I could find out a way to know the space between the two widgets on the row and once it is X distance away, it turns into the minimised version.

I have tried 'off methods' like counting how many characters each item in the array has and making a number, but as it expands, it'll turn into the tablet and then desktop layout, therefore will not be dependable to rely on it or MediaQuery.of(context).size.

Hopefully what I am saying makes sense.

Picture to show what I mean:

minimise: true
[image: if gap is not wide enough]

minimise: false
[image: if gap is wide]

Thanks for any advice you can give.

```
    class ListCardChipsWithActionBar extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //print('categoryList is ${categoriesList.length}');
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: ListCardCategoryChips(
            categories: categoriesList,
          ),
        ),
        ListCardActionBar(
          minimised: true,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: please add a picture of what you want

Comment: @veneno hi mate, hopefully this makes it clearer

Comment: you want to find the width of `ListCardCategoryChips` widget? when it collapse or expand?

Comment: @veneno, i want somehow say, when the distance is too close, turn my boolean to true. As these chips could have 3 or 4 and could posssibly be long, they can wrap to the next line, but if it circumed to that, i would rather minimise the actionbar and give it as much space as possible.

Comment: I have considered using FittedBox with scaledown but it seems to increase the container size, which is a huge shame. Would work for what I would like to achieve though if it didn't do this odd behaviour.